# Rotation by Euler Angles using SphericalPlot3D

Tags: manipulate, animation, rotation

I am new to Mathematica and I am trying to create a small animation using `SphericalPlot3D`. Essentially I have a 3D figure defined in `SphericalPlot3D[Combination of SphericalHarmonics(l,m)]`. The output is exactly as I want it and all is well for now.

I am trying to make the 3D figure rotate on itself using Euler Angles technique for parametrisation of motion with respect to an internal reference frame. I know that `GeometricTransformation[...,Euler Rotate]` works on `Graphics3D` but it appears that the `GeometricTransformation` does not work with `SphericalPlot3D`. I have tried to define my figure in `Graphics3D` without success... If anyone could help, that would be very much appreciated

Here is the code for my figure:

```
Manipulate[SphericalPlot3D[1 + b*Cos[g]*1/4 Sqrt[5/π] (-1 + 3 Cos[t]^2) + 
   (b/Sqrt[2])*Sin[g] (1/4 E^(-2 I p) Sqrt[15/(2 π)] Sin[t]^2 + 
    1/4 E^(2 I p) Sqrt[15/(2 π)] Sin[t]^2), 
   {t, 0, Pi},  {p, 0, 2*Pi}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], 
 {b, 0, 0.4}, {g, 0, Pi/3}]
```

Comment: does this help: `sp1 = With[{b = 0.5, g = 2}, 
            SphericalPlot3D[
                1 + 1/4 b Cos[g] Sqrt[
                            5/π] (-1 + 
                                3 Cos[t]^2) + (b Sin[
                                    g] (1/4 E^(-2 I p) Sqrt[15/(2 π)] Sin[t]^2 + 
                                        1/4 E^(2 I p) Sqrt[15/(2 π)] Sin[t]^2))/Sqrt[2], {t, 
                    0, π}, {p, 0, 2 π}]];
em = EulerMatrix[{π/3, π/2, π/4}];
Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, em] &, sp1, {1}], 
    PlotRange -> All]`?

Comment: Yes! That's in the direction i wish to go in. I intend to make an animation of the figure so that it rotate on its own.  i'll add varying parameters to the EulerMatrix now and see how it goes. Thanks !

Comment: Laudicina, welcome to mma.se. I posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can `MapAt` your `GeometricTransformation` at level `{1}` of the `SphericalPlot3D`:

```
Manipulate[Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, EulerMatrix[{angle1, angle2, angle3}]] &,
  SphericalPlot3D[1 +  b*Cos[g]*1/4 Sqrt[5/π] (-1 + 3 Cos[t]^2) + 
   (b/Sqrt[2])* Sin[g] (1/4 E^(-2 I p) Sqrt[15/(2 π)] Sin[t]^2 + 
    1/4 E^(2 I p) Sqrt[15/(2 π)] Sin[t]^2), 
   {t, 0, Pi}, {p, 0, 2*Pi}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], {1}], PlotRange -> All],
 {b,  0, 0.4}, {g, 0, Pi/2}, 
 {{angle1, Pi/3}, Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/8], SetterBar },
 {{angle2, Pi/2}, Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/8],  SetterBar} ,
 {{angle3, Pi/4}, Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/8], SetterBar } ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much kglr! I had managed to figure the manipulate part by myself but cheers for the swift reply